# How do you skip a number which you've already visited in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, leaderboard

I'm trying to create a leaderboard system by using a merge sort algorithm that sorts the scores in ascending order and then sorts the usernames by their score. I then use a for loop that displays the scores in descending order. The code in the image works perfectly fine when each user has a unique score and duplicate scores do not exist. However, I am having a problem when more than one user has the same score (i.e. there are duplicate scores).

For example, if two users have the same score (in this case 5), the wrong username is displayed. I believe this is because it only looks at the first occurrence of the sorted score. Hence, it's overwriting the original name. Is there any way I can skip the first occurrence of the duplicate number after it has been visited?

```
string[] UsernameAndScoresArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"UsernamesAndScores.txt");
            string[] UnsortedUsernamesArray = new string[UsernameAndScoresArray.Length];
            int[] UnsortedScoresArray = new int[UsernameAndScoresArray.Length];
            string UsernameAndScore = "";
            string Username = "";
            int Score = 0;
            int position = 0;

          

            for (int i = 0; i < UsernameAndScoresArray.Length; i++)
            {
                //Locates the username and scores and stores them in an 'unsorted array'
                UsernameAndScore = UsernameAndScoresArray[i];
                position = UsernameAndScore.IndexOf(':');
                Username = UsernameAndScore.Substring(0, position);
                UnsortedUsernamesArray[i] = Username;
                position = UsernameAndScore.IndexOf(':');
                Score = int.Parse(UsernameAndScore.Remove(0, position + 1));
                UnsortedScoresArray[i] = Score;
            }


            //Sorts the Scores in ascending order using the merge sort algorithm
            SortedArray = MergeSort(UnsortedScoresArray);
            SortedUsernames = new string[SortedArray.Length];
            


            for (int i = 0; i < UnsortedScoresArray.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int a = 0; a < SortedArray.Length; a++)
                {
                    if (UnsortedScoresArray[i] == SortedArray[a])
                    {
                        //The usernames are sorted based on the scores
                        SortedUsernames[a] = UnsortedUsernamesArray[i];
                    }
                }
            }
           

            int place = 0;
            for (int i = SortedArray.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                //The place, username and number of points are displayed in descending order  
                place++;
                Username = SortedUsernames[i];
                Score = SortedArray[i];
                ListBoxLeaderBoardPlaceAndUser.Items.Add(place + ":                        " + Username);
                ListBoxLeaderboardScore.Items.Add(Score);
            }
```

```
//This is an example of the error 
UnsortedScoresArray[]     = {46, 7, 5, 10, 5}
UnsortedUsernamesArray[]  = {User1, User2, User3, User4, User5}   
SortedScoresArray[]       = {5, 5, 7, 10, 46}
SortedUsernamesArray[]    = {User5, User5, User2, User4, User1}
```

It should say `SortedUsernamesArray[] = {User3, User5, User2, User4, User1}`

Comment: you could remove already visited scores from the list

Comment: Do you mean remove visited scores from the unsorted scores array? If I remove scores from that array would it not affect the position of the other usernames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do you skip a number which you've already visited in an array?

By remembering the position, for example, in a `HashSet`. Here's how I'd adapt your code to do that:

```
var usedAlready = new HashSet<int>();

for (int a = 0; a < SortedArray.Length; a++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < UnsortedScoresArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (UnsortedScoresArray[i] == SortedArray[a] && !usedAlready.Contains(i))
        {
            SortedUsernames[a] = UnsortedUsernamesArray[i];
            usedAlready.Add(i);

            // We already found the user for position a, no need to continue the inner loop.
            break;  
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've switched your loops around (first `a` (through SortedArray), then `i`).

Comment: Thank you so much! This works! 
Would a list also be a suitable data structure instead of a Hashset?

Comment: @Sanj_05: Yes, a list also works, but a hash set is faster in this case, since it's optimized for fast `Contains`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also `sort user by score`:

```
        int[] UnsortedScoresArray = { 46, 7, 5, 10, 5 };
        string[] UnsortedUsernamesArray = { "User1", "User2", "User3", "User4", "User5" };
        int[] sortedScoresArray=new int[UnsortedScoresArray.Length];
        string[] sortedUsernamesArray = new string[UnsortedUsernamesArray.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < UnsortedScoresArray.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < UnsortedScoresArray.Length; j++)
            {
                if (UnsortedScoresArray[i] > UnsortedScoresArray[j])
                {
                    int temp;
                    temp = UnsortedScoresArray[i];
                    UnsortedScoresArray[i] = UnsortedScoresArray[j];
                    UnsortedScoresArray[j] = temp;

                    string temp2 = UnsortedUsernamesArray[i];
                    temp2 = UnsortedUsernamesArray[i];
                    UnsortedUsernamesArray[i] = UnsortedUsernamesArray[j];
                    UnsortedUsernamesArray[j] = temp2;
                }
            }

        }
        sortedScoresArray = UnsortedScoresArray;
        sortedUsernamesArray = UnsortedUsernamesArray;
```

### result:

[image]

Comment: Have you just done a bubble sort?

Comment: @Sanj_05 Babel sort to sort the Scores and `sort the users at the same time`.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem, I would use a **dictionary**. I know it is a bother to get an answer that suggests a completely different data structure but eventually, you will get benefitted from its use.

I like this approach:

```
var dict = Enumerable.Range(0, keys.Length).ToDictionary(i => keys[i], i => values[I]);
```

Comment: If you really want the code to be expandable and efficient you've got to use one of the appropriate data structures each time. Take that from a guy that always wants to change the bare minimum in his code. But unfortunately, that's not always the case. If you use a dict the pairs will be, let us say, protected from such problems and the accessibility will definitely be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to solve such an issue in C# would be to

1. store both user name and score in the same data structure

   ```
   public class UserAndScore
   {
       public string User { get; }
       public int Score { get; }

       public UserAndScore(string user, int score)
       {
           User = user;
           Score = score;
       }
   }
   ```
2. and then use the built-in sort functionality of .NET to do the work for you:

   ```
   UserAndScore[] unsorted = new[]
   {
       new UserAndScore("User1", 46),
       new UserAndScore("User2", 7),
       // ...
   };

   // No need to re-invent the wheel... let .NET do the sorting!
   UserAndScore[] sorted = unsorted.OrderBy(u => u.Score).ToArray();
   ```

[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QXdE5l)